# WinForms app GUI update (WPF, WEB)

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface, optimization

I am working on a medium-large WinForms ERP solution.
Recently a question was raised on how much time would it take us to change our entire GUI from WinForms to WPF(for example).

One of the problems I see is the fact our forms also contain business code and this means we will also need to rewrite some of the business logic beside the design update and event handling.

I would like to see exactly how many forms contain business code, but the idea of manually checking each form does not seem very appealing.

Any suggestions on how can this be done more elegant? (any tools, using diagrams?)

Any other ideas, heads up, tips on this GUI update will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Dependeing on your application UI complexity, it can be hard, since learning WPF is not so easy, as winforms. MVVM is usually prefered to keep business logic and UI seperate.

For example, in my project, I had business logic seperately from the UI and I could switch them really easily without any rewrite(UI). That's MVVM :)